# Get filename from textFileStream in spark 2.1

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark, streaming

I would like to concatenate filename to data of a `csv` file read by `spark streaming`.

Actually I use this method to create stream listener :

`val lines: DStream[String] = streamingContext.textFileStream("file://" + dirPath)`

Note: I use a non `HDFS` file system

Answer (score 0):

You can use own fileStream:

```
JavaPairInputDStream<Text, Text> dStream = jssc.fileStream("dir", Text.class, Text.class, WholeTextFileInputFormat.class);
```

In Scala it should look like:

```
val dStream = jssc.fileStream[Text, Text, WholeTextFileInputFormat]("dir");
```

Then you have DStream of `(path, file content)`. You can parse it to more comfortable format by using:

```
val convertedDStream = dStream.map((x, y) => (x.toString(), y.toString())
```

Comment: Except that in Spark, most of the time you're dealing with files that won't fit in memory, so WholeTextFileInputFormat is a problem.